# theme profile2 fields on registration form

Tags: users

I have two profile types
teacher and student

so far I have used profile2 module and the profile 2 registration path module.
I have the core fields added

I am trying to add profile2 fields to my user-registration template

So far my template looks like this

```
<?php
print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
?>


<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); // prints the username field ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['mail']); // prints the mail field ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']); // prints the password fields ?>


<?php print drupal_render($form['actions']['submit']); // print the submit button ?>
password is not being displayed
```

I am not sure how i can add profile2 fields to my registration form.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://drupal.org/node/1779256) should help you in achieving it.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Normally, answers with just links aren't considered good ones.  Can you provide a short summary of how this will help with Profile 2 fields?

Answer (score 1):

Given Andrew's link, I found the solution to get a profile form array.

First, check 'Show during user account registration' under your profile configuration.

Then call

```
drupal_get_form('user_register_form')
```

That's it !